# ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 99872 elements to shape [1,125,1,8]

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to make a model with sample size 125*8
my input shape is (12484, 8) but i is giving me this error:

> ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 99872 elements to shape
>   [1,125,1,8] (1000 elements) for 'Reshape_9' (op: 'Reshape') with input
>   shapes: [1,12484,1,8], [4] and with input tensors computed as partial
>   shapes: input[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4QWz.png) = [1,125,1,8].

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1,1),padding="same", data_format="channels_last",input_shape= (8,125,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (5, 5),padding="same", activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())


_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_73 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 125, 64)        1664      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_23 (MaxPooling (None, 4, 63, 64)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_74 (Conv2D)           (None, 4, 63, 64)         102464    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_24 (MaxPooling (None, 2, 32, 64)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)          (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_45 (Dense)             (None, 5)                 20485     
=================================================================
Total params: 124,613
Trainable params: 124,613
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None


x_train= tf.reshape(x_train,[1,125,1,8])


model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=150,
          batch_size= 125)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=125, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

**Output**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1588   try:
-> 1589     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1590   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 99872 elements to shape [1,125,1,8] (1000 elements) for 'Reshape_9' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [1,12484,1,8], [4] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1,125,1,8].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-4e8b18efb44b> in <module>()
      1 #x_train= tf.reshape(x_train,[-1,288, 512, 3])
      2 
----> 3 x_train= tf.reshape(x_train,[1,125,1,8])
      4 
      5 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py in reshape(tensor, shape, name)
   7429   if _ctx is None or not _ctx._eager_context.is_eager:
   7430     _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
-> 7431         "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
   7432     _result = _op.outputs[:]
   7433     _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    785         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
    786                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 787                          op_def=op_def)
    788       return output_structure, op_def.is_stateful, op
    789 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)
   3412           input_types=input_types,
   3413           original_op=self._default_original_op,
-> 3414           op_def=op_def)
   3415 
   3416       # Note: shapes are lazily computed with the C API enabled.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in __init__(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)
   1754           op_def, inputs, node_def.attr)
   1755       self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, grouped_inputs,
-> 1756                                 control_input_ops)
   1757     else:
   1758       self._c_op = None

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1590   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1591     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1592     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1593 
   1594   return c_op

ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 99872 elements to shape [1,125,1,8] (1000 elements) for 'Reshape_9' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [1,12484,1,8], [4] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1,125,1,8].
```

[Data looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4QWz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the total sum of elemnts must allways be the same when reshaping.

You are getting this error because 1*125*1*8 != 99872

Your input shape is defined as: input_shape= (8,125,1)

Convolution2D expects: (batch, rows, cols, channels)

Your original x_train shape is: [1,12484,1,8]

You need to verify your channels, rows and cols then reshape accordingly.

Comment: Could you please tell me what can i do now. Shall i add total number of samples?

Comment: My input is not image so, i think my number of channels is 1, is there any other way to find channels?

Comment: Could you please tell me what can i do now. I am trying to solve this from last week. when i try to fix one thing i gives mean other error. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit better what you are actually trying to achieve. What is your data? What does the different dimensions in x_train actually represent?

Comment: I am trying to do EMG classification with 5 gestures.  In my data set, i have 125*8(rows and columns) for one gesture and for training total rows and columns are 12484*8, 8 columns represents data of 8 electrodes.

Answer (score 1):

Reshape error is expected because of how VegardKT explained it.

As I understand it, you want to first try the network on sample subset of data with 125 examples rather than 12484. Then you do not need to reshape, but slicing should do the job.

If my understanding of your problem is correct,

1] Comment out the line for reshape()

2] Have model fit to x_train[125,:] and y_train[125,:] (Just select first 125 rows and all columns from training data and label sets.)

Please let me know if I am misinterpreting something here.

Comment: First  125 rows are labeled as  1, next 125 rows as two and so on... when i try input shape(12484,8,1) and comment reshape lines, it gives me following error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_5_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 1)

Comment: i am using 125 * 8 dimension just we use 32*32 for image.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure about the meaning of the data you have. If your data is public, could you please post the link to the dataset, what each instance in dataset mean and describe the problem to be solved in terms of data? 
1] If you want (125, 8) to treat as single input to 2D conv-net then your total number of rows should have matched to a multiple of 125.(but it doesn't with 12484 rows)
2] If your each row label is mentioning label(one out of 5 gestures) based on 8 electrode readings at that time(as I interpreted from the data snippet you attached) standard NN might be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you Jaideep. Actually data set is not public. if i try 1×8 for one sample in convolution2d then i does not work. i can use it like that. I am just new in deep net. if i use simple Network with multiple dense layers then accuracy is very low.

Comment: Actually, i do not understand what i have to give as input shape and what batch size i can use, if i treat each row as sample.